# Drupal 7 comments spam with Captcha installed

Tags: 7, comments

I have a multilanguage - multidomain website developed in Drupal 7, and the database have been flooded with spam comments, even if I have Captcha module (image) installed. The spam comments are from 60 different IPs, and I have seen attempts to add node and add user (which is blocked) in the incidents reports.

So I cannot block so many IPs at the risk of them being dynamical and loosing potential users.

What could I do to prevent the spam and also to prevent the attacks? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**"to prevent the attacks"** - not much can be done here. If an attempt to access node/add page ends with access denied page, its ok. You cant prevent users from entering urls in their browsers.

As for spam in comments, try some different modules for Captcha ([Google reCaptcha with noCaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) for example).
For different aproach, [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) can help limiting "robots" behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I have added Honeypot module and the spam has stopt completely, and I hope, definitely.

Comment: As for the attacks, if they are serious, a white list approach could be tried, i.e., only a given bunch of predefined IPs are authorized to access those potentially harmful pages ( node/add, user/add ).